# refactor common handle method for all my services

Tags: angular, angular6

In all my services, I have the same method:

```
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (data: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      this.toastr.error(data.error.error);
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
```

And I call it:

```
all(): Observable<Category[]> {
    const listUrl = this.categoriesUrl;
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(listUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => this.toastr.success('success')),
        catchError(this.handleError('allCategories', []))
      );
  }
```

How should I refactor it to have it in only one place and that each service can easily refer to it ?

Comment: You could wrap it in its own service, export it and reuse it across all the other ones.

Comment: why don't you use httpInterceptor?